# Why does gganimate fail to order lines correctly by date with transition_reveal?

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I'm aiming to reproduce an animated figure by Ed Hawkins on climate change in `R` with `gganimate`. The figure is called [climate spiral](https://svs.gsfc.nasa.gov/4975). While a static `ggplot` figure shows the correct order of lines by year (the most recent data on top), the animated plot with `transition_reveal()` results in a wrong order of the lines.

Here is a reproducible example code with synthetic data:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(gganimate)
library(RColorBrewer) 

# Create monthly data from 1950 to 2020 (and a component for rising values with time)
df <- tibble(year = rep(1950:2020, each = 12), 
             month = rep(month.abb, 2020-1950+1)) %>%
  mutate(date = dmy(paste("01",month,year)),
         value = rnorm(n(), 0, 2) + row_number()*0.005) %>%
  with_groups(year, mutate, value_yr = mean(value))


temp <- df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = month(date, label=T), y = value, color = value_yr)) +
  geom_line(size = 0.6, aes(group = year)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, color = "white") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = c(-4,4), color = c("skyblue3","red1"), size = 0.2) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 1:12, color = "white", size = 0.2) +
  annotate("label", x = 12.5, y = c(-4,0,4), label = c("-4°C","0°C","+4°C"), 
           color = c("skyblue3","white","red1"), size = 2.5, fill = "#464950", 
           label.size = NA, label.padding = unit(0.1, "lines"),) +
  geom_point(x = 1, y = -11, size = 15, color = "#464950") + 
  geom_label(aes(x = 1, y = -11, label = year), 
             color = "white", size = 4, 
             fill = "#464950", label.size = NA) +
  coord_polar(start = 0) +
  scale_color_gradientn(colors = rev(brewer.pal(n=11, name = "RdBu")),
                        limits = range(df$value_yr)) +
  labs(x = "", y = "") + 
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        plot.background=element_rect(fill="#464950", color="#464950"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(margin = margin(t = -20, unit = "pt"), 
                                   color = "white"),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(), 
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "none")
```

Now, we can either save the plot as PNG or animate and save as GIF:

```
ggsave(temp, filename = "test.png", width = 5, height = 5, dpi = 320)

# Animate by date:
anim <- temp +
  transition_reveal(date) +
  ease_aes('linear')
  
output <- animate(anim, nframes = 100, end_pause = 30,
                  height = 5, width = 5, units = "in", res = 300)

anim_save("test.gif", output)
```

Let's see the results!

Static PNG:
[image]

Animated GIF:
[image]

At first glance, the results look equal, however, the detail shows differences (for instance, the marked blue line).

[image]

In this example code with synthetic data, the differences are minor. But with real data, the figures look pretty different as many red lines (recent data points with high temperatures) disappear in the background. So, how can you retain the order in `transition_reveal()` by date? Any help appreciated, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't the answer per se. This is the why. You'll have to tell me what you prefer given this information for me to give you a solution.

I tried a few things—each of which I was just sure would work but did not. So, I wanted to see what was happening in `ggplot`. My hunch proved correct. Your data is in order of `value_yr` in the `png`, not `year`.

I repeat this question at the end:

> Either you can put the animation in order of `value_yr` or you can put the color in `ggplot` in order by year. Which would you prefer?

How do I know? I extracted the assigned colors in the object.

```
tellMe <- ggplot_build(temp)$data[[1]]
head(tellMe)
#    colour x           y group PANEL flipped_aes size linetype alpha
# 1 #1E60A4 1 -1.75990067     1     1       FALSE  0.6        1    NA
# 2 #1E60A4 2 -0.08968196     1     1       FALSE  0.6        1    NA
# 3 #1E60A4 3 -0.69657130     1     1       FALSE  0.6        1    NA
# 4 #1E60A4 4 -0.10777727     1     1       FALSE  0.6        1    NA
# 5 #1E60A4 5  1.57710505     1     1       FALSE  0.6        1    NA
# 6 #1E60A4 6  1.63277369     1     1       FALSE  0.6        1    NA 

gimme <- tellMe %>% group_by(group) %>% 
  summarise(color = unique(colour)) %>% 
  print(n = 100) # there are less than 100, I just want them all

head(gimme)
# # A tibble: 6 × 2
#   group color  
#   <int> <chr>  
# 1     1 #1E60A4
# 2     2 #114781
# 3     3 #175290
# 4     4 #053061
# 5     5 #1C5C9E
# 6     6 #3E8BBF
```

To me, this indicated that the colors weren't in group order, so I wanted to see the colors to visualize the order.

I used this function. I know it came from a demo, but I don't remember which one. I looked just so I could include that here, but I didn't find it.

```
# this is from a demo (not sure which one anymore!
showCols <- function(cl=colors(), bg = "lightgrey",
                     cex = .75, rot = 20) {
  m <- ceiling(sqrt(n <-length(cl)))
  length(cl) <- m*m; cm <- matrix(cl, m)
  require("grid")
  grid.newpage(); vp <- viewport(w = .92, h = .92)
  grid.rect(gp=gpar(fill=bg))
  grid.text(cm, x = col(cm)/m, y = rev(row(cm))/m, rot = rot,
            vp=vp, gp=gpar(cex = cex, col = cm))
}

showCols(gimme$color)
```

The top left color is the oldest year, the value below it is the following year, and so on. The most recent year is the bottom value in the right-most column.

[image]

```
df %>% group_by(yr) %>% summarise(value_yr = unique(value_yr))
# they are in 'value_yr' order in ggplot, not year
# # A tibble: 71 × 2
#       yr value_yr
#    <int>    <dbl>
#  1  1950  0.0380 
#  2  1951 -0.215  
#  3  1952 -0.101  
#  4  1953 -0.459  
#  5  1954 -0.00130
#  6  1955  0.559  
#  7  1956 -0.457  
#  8  1957 -0.251  
#  9  1958  1.10   
# 10  1959  0.282  
# # … with 61 more rows
```

> Either you can put the animation in order of `value_yr` or you can put the color in `ggplot` in order by year. Which would you prefer?

---

---

#### Update

You won't use `transition_reveal` to group and transition by the same element. Unfortunately, I can't tell you why, but it seems to get stuck at 1958!

To make this gif on the left match that `ggplot` png on the right:

[image][image]

First, I modified the calls to `ggplot` and `geom_line`

```
  ggplot(aes(x = month(date, label = T), y = value, 
             group = yr, color = yr)) +
  geom_line(size = .6)
```

Then I tried to use `transition_reveal` but noticed that subsequent years were layered *underneath* other years. I can't account for that odd behavior. When I ran `showCol` after changing `temp,` the colors were in order. That ruled out what I had thought the problem was initially.

I modified the object `anim`, using `transition_manual` to force the order of the plot layers.

```
anim <- temp +
  transition_manual(yr, cumulative = T) +
  ease_aes('linear')
```

That's it. Now the layers match.
As to whether this would have worked before you changed the color assignment: original plot with manual transitions of the year on the left, `ggplot` png on the right:

[image][image]

It looks like that would've have worked, as well. So, my original drawn-out explanation wasn't nearly as useful as I thought, but at least you have a working solution now. (Sigh.)

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time and for your very informative answer. I have already learned a lot from your approach! First and foremost, I was not aware that ggplot orders the elements by the `color` aesthetic. Actually I hoped to sort the lines properly with the `group` aesthetic in `geom_line()` and the order of the dataframe itself. What I finally would like to see is a sorting by date (latest year on top) in both the static PNG and the animated GIF. I very much appreciate your help.

Comment: Just so I make sure I have this correct-you would like both to look like the GIF image that you have in your question? Or are you asking for the colors to be in order by year, as well?

Comment: The color should be given by `value_yr` which is the average annual temperature in the final plot (blue = low annual temperature, red = high annual temperature). However, I initially thought that the GIF was wrong and actually I still do (even though you showed that the PNG was also flawed). Let's do a simple test with `color = year` and only 10 years: [see the result here](https://gifyu.com/image/SphLh). For instance, the red line for 2010 is not on top but behind the other lines for earlier years. That's why gganimate does not behave as I expected. Thanks for your patience :)

Comment: Wow, yup. You're right. I've updated my answer with a solution that works (and kept my sheepish incorrectness in there). The updates at added at the bottom.

Comment: Wow, that finally solved the problem! Thanks a lot for sharing your skills! I think of writing a `gganimate` issue on Github as others might also encounter this problem.

Comment: That's a great idea. I'm sure others have run into this issue—many of whom didn't know that they had!